# Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. in CodeIgniter framework

Tags: reactjs, codeigniter, web-services, access-control

Am new to codeIgniter, I have build a REST web-services using code-igniter.

UI using react JS.

In postman web-service seems to working fine. But when I integrate in React JS it is throwing an error.

**Failed to load http://123.0.0.5:81/codeigniter-rest-api/index.php/auth/login: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
EmployeeLogin.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 
Failed to fetch**
[image]

**My web-service is :** 123.0.0.5:81/codeigniter-rest-api/index.php/auth/login

**My React server is :** localhost/3000

I have searched solution and I tried in my controller but not working.

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");    
    }
```

My react consume script is :

```
(async () => {
          const rawResponse = await fetch('http://123.0.0.5:81/codeigniter-rest-api/index.php/auth/login', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(datapost)
          });
          const content = await rawResponse.json();

          alert(content);
      })();
```

Comment: why was the request had `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`..? I thought it should be server side.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Yes I gone through document. Now working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change: `fetch('http://...)` to `fetch('https://...)` or `fetch('//...)`.

You cannot do a CrossOrigin request over HTTP, only HTTPS.